# X11 Forwarding Display is always :0

Tags: ssh, xorg, sshd, x11-forwarding

I've been trying for a few hours now to get X11 forwarding working from a remote host. I know it used to work and the host was physically moved and has not worked since. I am unsure if that is relevant but I'm including it in case it gives me an area to check.

The remote machine has `X11DisplayOffset 10` set, so we would expect the value of `DISPLAY` to be something like `:10` or `localhost:10` but it's always `:0`. So it seems like something could be overwriting it but I have no idea what would be.

Things I have tried:

- disabling access control with `xhost +` locally
- Adding `X11UseLocalhost no` and `X11Forwarding yes` to the remote machine's `sshd_config`
- Restarting the `sshd` service and the remote machine and my local machine.
- `ssh -vvvX` shows `debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0` so I am working under the assumption the connection is working fine.
- Checking none of my login scripts touch `DISPLAY`
- `iptables` shows it is not blocking port 6000
- I've enabled `all` incoming packet types from this host with `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p all -s {host ip} -j ACCEPT`
- `export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority` on remote machine
- I can xforward with other hosts so it's not hosed on my machine.
- Ensuring `xauth` is installed on the remote host.
- Manually setting `DISPLAY` to every combination of `localhost/127.0.0.1:0/10.[0]`
- Trying both `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y`

All I get:

```
$ xeyes 
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment so writing here. Will update after your reply.

Did you do `ssh -X host@ip` to connect?

Try running this in your remote pc:

```
export DISPLAY='IP:10.0'
```

**Note that IP is the local workstation’s IP(127.0.0.1) where you want the GUI application to be displayed.

Also make sure `xauth` is installed in your system

Restart sshd service or the whole workstation if possible and then try.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I've tried all of this - updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: It's currently on 18.04.5